# DRF 3.0: Sharing a single UniqueTogetherValidator among related Serializers with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I’m dealing with a set of Model classes which share some common attributes via inheritance:

```
class MyBaseModel(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        unique_together = (('system', 'code',),)

    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, unique=True, ...
    system = models.ForeignKey(System, ...
    code = models.CharField(...
    ...


class ModelA(MyBaseModel):
    ...

class ModelB(MyBaseModel):
    ...
```

Please note the presence of a unique_together constraint in Meta class.

A similar hierarchy would be convenient for the corresponding serializers;
I'm not sure whether I need to explicitly specify a UniqueTogetherValidator,
and currently investigating on this. 
But in case, I wonder how to express it in the base serializer class, as it
requires a queryset which is not known in advance:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueTogetherValidator


class MyBaseModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        exclude = ['date_created', 'created_by', ...

        validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=???.objects.all(),
                fields=('system', 'code')
            )
        ]


class ModelASerializer(MyBaseModelSerializer):
    class Meta(MyBaseModelSerializer.Meta):
        model = ModelA
    ...


class ModelBSerializer(MyBaseModelSerializer):
    class Meta(MyBaseModelSerializer.Meta):
        model = ModelB
    ...
```

How can I avoid repeating it for every single derived class, as in the following 
example ?

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueTogetherValidator


class MyBaseModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        exclude = ['date_created', 'created_by', ...


class ModelASerializer(MyBaseModelSerializer):
    class Meta(MyBaseModelSerializer.Meta):
        model = ModelA
        validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=ModelA.objects.all(),
                fields=('system', 'code')
            )
        ]
    ...


class ModelBSerializer(MyBaseModelSerializer):
    class Meta(MyBaseModelSerializer.Meta):
        model = ModelB
        validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=ModelB.objects.all(),
                fields=('system', 'code')
            )
        ]
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Model Serializer adds the `UniqueTogetherValidator` from model's `unique_together` constraints. You don't have give seperately.

Comment: Thank you; you're totally right: UniqueTogetherValidator comes for free from Model unique_together constraints.
However, the question remain: how can I share, if possible, a custom UniqueTogetherValidator among serializers via inheritance ?

Answer (score 0):

need override

```
unique_together = (('system', 'code',),)
```

in non abstract model